# Beaglebone Black Qt5 cross compilation error

Tags: qt5, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack

[Error in Qt while deploying Qt program in Beaglebone Black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DGJ42.png)

I have Debian 9 (stretch) in Beaglebone Black and workstation is Ubuntu 16.04. I have cross-compiled Qt5 for Beaglebone Black. BBB OS sysroot is mounted in /mnt/bbb-rootfs folder. What I need to install to remove these errors.

Configure command is with following arguments:-

./configure -device linux-beagleboard-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=/home/gunjan/qt5bbb/gcc-linaro-6.3.1-2017.02-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot /mnt/bbb-rootfs -opensource -confirm-license -optimized-qmake -reduce-exports -release -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5bbb -hostprefix /usr/local/qt5bbb -qt-zlib -no-opengl -qt-libpng -nomake examples -nomake tests -no-xkb -no-kms -no-eglfs -xcb -no-opengl -no-egl -gui -widgets -openssl -no-qml-debug -v 2>&1 | tee -a /home/gunjan/qt5bbb/qtbase-configure2-log.txt